# How to output MP3s to a sound card

Tags: linux, perl, audio, mp3

I'm trying to write some code in perl (specifically) to output sound (specifically, MP3s) to my sound card. I've not seen any examples of outputting any sound to the soundcard in perl, so examples of that would be helpful.

My question is, how do audio players output sound to the sound card? Do they convert them to WAV on the fly?

Comment: [It's… complicated.](http://blogs.adobe.com/penguinswf/2007/05/welcome_to_the_jungle.html) The difficult part is deciding at which level to hook into the stack (and this depends on what you actually want to do, *why* you want to play audio) and whether that's supported by a Perl module. Tim Nordenfur went ahead and named an obvious solution, but due to its integration with the SDL event loop which is designed for games it probably won't you do much good (except you *do* want to program a game). So please edit your question and add some more detail in order to receive a suitable recommendation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SDL::Sound](http://search.cpan.org/~kthakore/SDL_Perl-v2.2.6/lib/SDL/Sound.pm) solves this problem for WAV files. There are several packages for converting compressed MP3 files to WAV, such as [Audio::MPEG](http://search.cpan.org/~ptimof/Audio-MPEG-0.04/MPEG.pm#MP3_to_WAV) and [Audio::ConvTools](http://search.cpan.org/~mhooreman/Audio-ConvTools-0.08/lib/Audio/ConvTools.pm).

Answer (score 0):

Are you on Linux? If so you can do your logic in Perl and then shell out to some command line player, like [`mpg123`](http://www.mpg123.de/). Not a pure Perl solution, but gets the job done.